# Deciding a time out time in selenium automation framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the best practise to decide value for timeouts ?  Like say, I declare 15 seconds, then why 15, any calculation?

Comment: are you talking about `implicitly_wait()`? If so, usually anywhere between 15 and 30 is fine

Comment: and what about explicit wat ?

Comment: that depends on how long it takes for the webdriver to find a specific element. There can be instance when a particular element takes more than a minute to load. just a matter of experimenting with different values

Answer (score 2):

Timeouts are very individual. It depends on your infrastructure, application and connection.

You should be careful specifying timeouts for explicit and implicit waits.
The detailed info on waits can be found:

- http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
- http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp